# Why are records not being stored to the db when testing with VCR?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, vcr

I have an interactor `foo` with method `perform` on it which makes an API call, and records the response through ActiveRecord. It works fine. I have a spec for it that triggers the method with FactoryBot data, then checks the db for the expected records. This also works fine. However, when I wrap the call in a `VCR.use_cassette`, the call is made (and resulting cassette created), but the db records don't seem to be written. What am I missing?

spec looks like this:

```
it 'should do a thing' do
  bar = FactoryGirl.create(:bar)

  VCR.use_cassette('foo/cassette') do
    MyInteractor.perform(bar)
  end

  record = BarRecord.find_by(bar_id: bar.id)
  expect(record.status.to_sym).to be(:success)
end
```

`perform` method looks roughly like this:

```
def perform(bar)
  uri = URI.parse("<url>")
  req = Net::HTTP::Post.new(uri, 'Content-Type' => 'application/json')
  req.basic_auth Settings.username, Settings.password
  req['Accept'] = 'Application/json'
  req.body = post_params.to_json

  https = Net::HTTP.new(uri.host, uri.port)
  https.use_ssl = true
  res = https.request(req)

  record = BarRecord.new(bar_id: bar.id)
  record.status = JSON.parse(res.body)["status"]
  record.save!
  record
end
```

`BarRecord` should be created by the call to `perform`. Without VCR it is.

Comment: Share what's inside `MyInteractor.perform`

Comment: Protip: you can just use `record.reload` instead of `record = BarRecord.find_by(bar_id: bar.id)` to refresh the record attributes from the database.

Comment: @AmitPatel updated

Comment: @max `Bar` != `BarRecord`. `BarRecord` is a sort of audit log on `Bar` and gets created when you call the interactor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the curious, there was in fact nothing wrong with VCR. I was storing items with a fixed timestamp, and then reading them with a dynamic one that didn't overlap. Full pebkac.